# Recommended way to hit the database within the DAO's in Spring3.1.1 (hibernate4)?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am upgrading my project from **spring 3.0.5 & hibernate 3** to **spring 3.1.1 & hibernate 4.1**

I use **org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport** extensively. In concrete **HibernateTemplate**; like in this snippet:

```
public class MenuDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements MenuDao, Serializable {

public List<Menu> getMenus() {
    return getHibernateTemplate().find("from Menu menu");
}

//etc

}
```

But I read that HibernateTemplate **isn't recommended for use anymore**.

So, what’s the recommended way to hit the database within the DAO's in Spring3.1.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inject an EntityManager and use it directly.

```
public class MenuDaoImpl implements MenuDao {


@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

...

}
```

Here's a [good example on the SpringSource blog](http://blog.springsource.org/2006/08/07/using-jpa-in-spring-without-referencing-spring/).

Comment: What are the advantages of your suggested approach, based on EntityManager over the one based in SessionFactory, suggested by steve.hanson?

Comment: They're roughly equivalent: SessionFactory is the pure Hibernate way of doing it, EntityManager is the JPA way. If you're always going to use Hibernate as your ORM layer, then there's really not much in it.

However, if you might change your ORM implementation (to EclipseLink, or some other JPA provider), then using those interfaces (like EntityManager) now would be beneficial.

Additionally, coding against the standard JPA interfaces opens the potential for wider tooling support. In practice, though, Hibernate tooling is at least as good.

I'd say that today, either is fine.

Answer (score 2):

As of Hibernate 3.0.1, Spring recommends the use of `SessionFactory`, rather than the `HibernateTemplate`.

From the [Spring 3.0 HibernateTemplate API docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/):

> NOTE: As of Hibernate 3.0.1, transactional Hibernate access code can
>   also be coded in plain Hibernate style. Hence, for newly started
>   projects, consider adopting the standard Hibernate3 style of coding
>   data access objects instead, based on
>   SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().

Example:

```
public class MenuDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<Menu> getMenus() {
        return (List<Menu>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession.createQuery("from Menu").list();
    }
}
```